# Get the list of users from User Profile in SP2013 with programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, web-part

I have to get all the users from **User Profiles**.
I have to implement search on those users on the basis of **First Name & Last Name**.
**This question may be repeated** but I don't get use-full solution so posted.

Comment: SharePoint on premises OR SharePoint online and Are u using c#?

Comment: SharePoint on Premises and using C# language.

Comment: Which language you are using to develop webpart?

Comment: Ram,what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Akshay, Working on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163182.aspx article.

Comment: Ram, The code you are trying is for getting users from User Profiel service. For that you have to create and configure user profile service in central admin and need to synchronize it with AD.Have you done this?

Comment: I have updated my answer..Please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add Assembly :** `Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll`

**Add Namespace :**  `using Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles;`

```
try
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
            UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
            foreach (UserProfile usrprofile in profileManager)
           {
                if (usrprofile.Properties.GetPropertyByName("FirstName") != null)
                {
                    string firstName = Convert.ToString(usrprofile["FirstName"].Value);
                }
                if (usrprofile.Properties.GetPropertyByName("LastName") != null)
                {
                    string lastName  = Convert.ToString(usrprofile["LastName"].Value);
                }           
           }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: #Vishal, 
I have made little bit modification in the question, please check it.
Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: That is implemented :)

Comment: We can do that like this also-                
                var userProfiles = profileManager.GetEnumerator();
                while (userProfiles.MoveNext())
                {
 if (userProfile["FirstName"].Value != null)
                    {
                        firstName = userProfile["FirstName"].Value.ToString();
                    }
                    if (userProfile["LastName"].Value != null)
                    {
                        lastName = userProfile["LastName"].Value.ToString();
                    }
 }