# write the KQL Query on the User Profile with programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I have to **write an query** to fetch the all records who are belongs to IT department or whose last name starts with A on the User Profile.
I don't want to iterate all the items instead of this, I have to fire an query and get the instant result.
Is it possible or not with the SP2013 programmatically? Please share the example/ reference so that anyone can do it easily with the reference.

[Link for my old question without KQL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194140/get-the-list-of-users-from-user-profile-in-sp2013-with-programmatically).

I have used following code

```
public DataTable GetItemsFromSearch(string query, string rootWebUrl)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = null;
        using (var siteCollection = new SPSite(rootWebUrl))
        {
            var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(siteCollection) { QueryText = query };

            var searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
                            
            string[] words1 =  FieldTemplate.Split(';');
                            string lastName = string.Empty;
                            for (int i = 0; i < words1.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                propertyName = string.Empty;
                                string[] properties = words1[i].Split('|');
                                propertyName = properties[0].ToString();
                                keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add(propertyName);
                            }

            

            try
            {
                ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);

                var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);

                var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();

                if (resultTable != null)
                {
                    dataTable = resultTable.Table;
                }
            }
```

**I don't getting anything from the dataTable. It's empty.**
But I can get the data with **profileManager.Search("Text")**.
So what is wrong in the above code?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? What language are you using? Post the code that you have tried.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Please check the Question, I have updated with the code.